# How to increase stroke of svg image?

Tags: css, svg, stroke

I have an svg file, I keep increasing the `stroke-width` but it does not change anything:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 487 488" width="487" height="488">
    <defs>
        <image  width="487" height="488" id="img1" stroke-width="1000" href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
    </defs>
    <style>
        tspan { white-space:pre }
    </style>
    <use id="Background copy" href="#img1" x="0" y="0"/>
</svg>
```

Any ideas on how to change the stroke-width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the stroke-width attribute for an image element that is embedding an inline PNG. "data:image/png;base64" should be your hint.

Why would you expect this to change anything? The inline png is a bitmap image - just because you embed it in a SVG image element, it doesn't magically convert it to a vector. (And even if it was an inline SVG fragment, the image element doesn't take a stroke-width attribute and that would not propagate down into the data URI).

If you want the stroke in that image to be bigger, extract that inlined PNG into a new .png file and edit it in Photoshop or alternatively redraw the image from scratch with SVG drawing elements (path etc.).

Comment: I have tried to edit the .png in photoshop but I'm unable to increase its stroke width since i cant edit the png's stroke

Comment: It's a png. It's just pixels. It's not a vector image or a PDF, so it doesn't encode the concept of lines, circles and strokes. There are no objects. It's all just pixels. That's what a .png (and .jpg and .bmp) is. Pixels.